# How to load next page using youtube_explode_dart in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

How can I load the next video batch after displaying the first 20 videos by youtube_explode_dart?

my package version

> youtube_explode_dart: ^2.0.2

```
Future<void> getData() async {
isLoading = true;
String query;

if (searchQueryController.text.trim().isEmpty) {
  query = 'trending hindi punjabi english and bhojpuri songs';
} else {
  query = searchQueryController.text.trim();
}

data = await yt.search.search(query, filter: SortFilters.relevance);

await data!.nextPage();

setState(() {
  searchQueryList = data!.toList();
});

isLoading = false;
```

}

this is the code I am using to fetch the first 20 videos and there is also **data!.nextPage()** to fetch the next batch but it is not working and just refreshing the same page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You were not using the data that was return from data!.nextPage();

```
final nextPageData = await data!.nextPage(); // check here

    setState(() {

  //    if you want to add to your initial data
  //    searchQueryList = [...data!.toList(), ...nextPageData?.toList()];

  //    if you want replace initial data
        searchQueryList = (nextPageData??[]).toList();
    });
```